# Custom made dashboard - Dashboard framework

Tags: cms

I want to create several custom web dashboards to display data from multiple sources: scripts, InfluxDB, Postgresql, Grafana, etc.

Which frameworks can you recommend to limit coding time? Or even a CMS or equivalent?
I don't plan to create everything from scratch.

Ideally I can drag-and-drop charts (or modify a configuration file to add charts), have user management (one user can only see a set of dashboards), and I can add code to some pages for interactivity (alert acknowledgement for example).

I don't want to rely on external services (Google Dashboard). This will be hosted on my own internal webserver.